# how to check if Div exist in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Hi guys i want to check if **DIV test** exists in iframe show alert"

```
 <html>
  <body>
   <div id="test">test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I loaded this html file to my iframe. How can i check if **DIV test** exists ?

```
<iframe src="1.html" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('frameDemo');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var test = innerDoc.getElementById('test');

if(test != undefined) {

    alert('Exists');

}else{

    alert('Do no Exists');
}
```

:)